# Executing My Program Using Execl

Tags: c, file, file-io, printf

I wrote a program which takes a file name as an argument, opens the file, parses its content and does some stuff. I am writing a test program that will test that program by executing it.

Here is my test class:

```
int main () {

    FILE *input;
    input = fopen("file.txt", "w+");
    if (input == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create a new file");
    exit(1);
    }

    fprintf(input, "8\n");

    if (execl("./a.out", "./a.out", "file.txt", NULL) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error forking program\n");
    exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I open `file.txt`, I only see a blank file. My `./a.out` program is giving out a parsing error (`fgets` is returning NULL) and I assume its because `file.txt` is not being written into. What's the problem here? How can I debug such an issue? Why would `fprintf` ever not write into a file?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to flush the file -- see fflush. On POSIX systems you can also use setbuf or setvbuf if you want to flush on every printf.

Edit: Actually, in your code, the appropriate thing to do is simply fclose the file before the execl; that of course flushes it. Also, you don't need "w+", and "input" isn't a very good name for a file you're writing to.

Additionally, you should name your programs appropriately rather than leaving them named a.out; execl of a.out is particularly dangerous as you don't know which program is being run. If you were to compile the above program without a -o flag, it would overwrite a.out and invoking it would lead to recursive execution of itself, resulting in an infinite loop. Fortunately it would not flood your system with processes because you do not do a fork, contrary to your (erroneous) error message.

A nit: don't forget to end your printfs with \n ... the first one is lacking. Be particularly scrupulous about this in error messages, which don't get thorough testing.

Comment: Thanks works! Why is `fopen(argv[1], "r")` failing in my program now?

Comment: Why would I need to use `rewind` on the file once opened with `a+`?

Comment: @Darksky You're responding to the wrong answer but ... "a+" says to open for append but allow reading. You need to rewind or seek in order to read what you wrote. If you don't intend to read the opened file, don't include the +. Note that reading the file from *another process* doesn't require the + flag ... it isn't an attribute of the file, just an instruction to the stdio library of how to treat it.

Comment: Thanks. I actually ended up forking and using `pipe` and `dup2`. I still had to close the file at the end. As for `a.out`, I am probably going to create a `make` package for the project. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you want no clearly specified.But I think you use ./a.out which is same image of this program.Then

**first problem** is you have no arrangement for command-line arguments.

**second problem** is you use

```
fopen("test.txt","w+");
```

//open file if exist and truncate it.if not exist then create it

That is it is always a fresh file.no previous content available .If you want previous file contents also then use

```
fopen("test.txt","a");
```

To read from the file, also use

```
fopen("test.txt", "a+");
```

You will also have to call `rewind()` on the file when `a+` is used, and the file already exists.

**Third problem** you replace current image by its another image so working like recursion.and no proper closing of file maintained so some time out put buffer not flushed properly.

**This is work like infinite loop** .So what is the use of it I don't suggest this program to do.

Comment: Thanks! I edited your answer - I added a few things I just found out. Both answers were right. Which one would I mark as correct?

Comment: @Darksky You previously accepted my answer, which answered your question and you said that worked. There is nothing in your question about opening for append and so on. If you have additional questions, you should post them, not engage in extended discussions in the comments.